# Views won't update in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

After beeing finally being happy with the results on my development machine i decided to deploy my Rails 4-app on my VPS using capistrano. As my stack i chose NGINX and Unicorn. Now i noticed a few things i need to change in order to make everything work in production, but somehow i am unable to update the views.

What i already did is:

1. Clearing the browser cache
2. Disabling the cache in config/production.rb by setting config.action_controller.perform_caching to false
3. Manually checking the files on the remote server using ssh
4. Restarting my server stack

In fact my local files are in sync with the ones on the production server, however i don't see any changes in my browser. What else can i do? Is there anything i missed? I appreciate
 any help.

Comment: may I ask how do you restart you stack? Are you sure unicorn has been restarted?

Comment: I am running a script which actually performs the following command: bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production. I just tested it manually and it seems to work fine. Then i start NGINX using: sudo service nginx restart.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Verify if you don't have remaining cache tmp files**

```
What i already did is:
    Disabling the cache in config/production.rb by setting config.action_controller.perform_caching to false
```

I assume that means the cache was enabled before, therefore some cache files could have been created earlier and are now served by NGINX without going through rails, and you did not mention that you manually cleared the cache

You can look into your "public" folder to see if there are cache files and delete them manually, but be sure to know what you are doing and don't delete files that may be used by another part of your application. Or you can try clearing the cache in your production server through the console

```
# from the root directory of your application, open your rails console
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails c
# Then in the console, type
> Rails.cache.clear
```

**2. Verify if there is no proxy caching**

It is possible that your page are cached by an external component, such as a proxy. You should check the output of the server from its local console. Log into your server console and run a `curl` to get the output of the page from localhost (do not use the server external IP) then look into the source to see if the output is updated or not. That will narrow down a bit the source of the problem for further investigation

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's somehow strange, but i can't see any cache files in my public folder and as i ran your suggested commands i got an error message telling me there is no cache folder in tmp.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you another idea